# nginx cache dir creation—strange behaviour

Tags: nginx, centos7, file-permissions, selinux

I have the following line (plus context) in my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path cache/  keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;
    ...
```

Since `nginx.conf` is in `/etc/nginx`, `cache/` corresponds to `/etc/nginx/cache`.
    drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 205 Jun 18 16:25/etx/nginx

( I have also tried this with absolute path `/apps/nginx/cache/`

```
drwx------. 2 nginx nginx 6 Jun 18 14:42 /apps/nginx
```

)

In either case, when I try to

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
```

it fails. `journalctl -u nginx` tells me the following:

```
... nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
... nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/etc/nginx/cache" failed (13: Permission denied)
... nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

(In the alternate scenario, it does say `"/apps/nginx/cache"` instead.)

I then tried to

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx-debug
```

and this starts without any issues, error or warning logs. It creates the `cache/` directory wherever specified in `nginx.conf`, and when I stop it and start the `nginx` service, this also starts normally.

I need to understand what causes this, so I can write my automation and configuration management to work out of the box.
My two hypotheses are:

1. It's a SELinux issue, and service/binary `nginx-debug` has different tags/restrictions to `nginx`.
2. The pre-flight check when starting `nginx` tries to create the directory as a different. unprivileged user, but `nginx-debug` skips these checks and thus creates the directory as root or nginx.

Any idea how to efficiently get to the bottom of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a selinux issue. Best way to check is to disable selinux and run your stuff.

```
setenforce 0       //setenforce 1 (to refinforce)
```

If its a selinux issue then you can try setting a context for the cache folder.

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_cache_t "/etc/nginx/cache(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -Rv /etc/nginx/
```

Verify the folder label.

```
sudo ls -lZ /etc/nginx/
```

Comment: This is a tightly controlled environment (read: bank). Not allowed to. :(